# Codeigniter 3 registration application: let user know email already exists via a flash message

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, flash-message

I have made a **Registration and Login** application with Codeigniter 3.

The Signup form validation makes sure that every *email* in the users table is *unique*, as illustrated bellow:

[image]

Instead of "The Email field must contain a unique value" below the e-mail field, I want a flash message to let the user know the provided email already exists and that he/she should **sigin in** instead of **signing up**:

[image]

I am using an `$email_exists` function inside an *if statement* but the function itself does not exist *yet*.

I want to make use of CI's `is_unique` inside the `$email_exists` function. How can I do this?

Is this a good approach to achieving the desired functionality?

My `signup()` function looks like this:

```
public function signup()
 {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[cpassword]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
        $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name'); 
        $email =  $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $date_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $verification_key = md5($email);
        $active = 0;
        $this->load->model('Usermodel');
        // Create account
        if ($this->Usermodel->user_register($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password, $date_created, $date_updated, $verification_key, $active)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("signup_sucess", "Your account was created. Your have to activate it before you can signin. We have send you an activation email at $email.");
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("signup_failure", "We ware unable to create your account");
        }
        redirect('signup'); 
    } else {
        $this->load->view('signup');
        if ($email_exists) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("email_exists", "The email address you provided already exists. Please signup.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: RTM: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: Go to the views folder and edit text  on `signup` file.

Comment: Why bother trying to use the is unique function? Just make a function that queries the database and if num rows greater than 0 return true (email exists)? Or just run a separate form validation first. And if run fails that mean it isn't unique and you can redirect with your flash message. If not define all the rules and redefine the email rule and run it like you are doing now?

Comment: @Alex Since I am using a framework, I believe it is a good idea to make use as much as possible of the "instruments" _it_ offers.

Comment: `$query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email)); return $query->num_rows() > 0;` 2 lines done without hacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for: if the registration details are *provided* and *valid*, register the new user, *unless* the email address he/she provides already exists in the database, in which case, instead of showing a validation error (remember: all the data, e-mail included *is* valid), urge the user to login and *redirect to login page*.

Register user John Doe, that was already registered:

[image: Register a user that already exists]

You are redirected to login page and "invited" to login.

[image: Invitation to login]

**This is the code:**

In the `Usermodel.php` file:

```
public function email_exists($email)
{   
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users', ['email' => $email]);
    return $query->num_rows() > 0;
}
```

In the `Signup.php` file:

```
public function signup()
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');
  $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
            $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name'); 
            $email =  $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $date_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $verification_key = md5($email);
            $active = 0;
            // Load user model
            $this->load->model('Usermodel');

            // If email does not already exist in the database 
            // signup new user
            if (!$this->Usermodel->email_exists($email)) {
                if ($this->Usermodel->user_register($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password, $date_created, $date_updated, $verification_key, $active)) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("signup_sucess", "Your account was created. Your have to activate it before you can signin. We have send you an activation email at $email.");
                } else {
                    // unless sigup does not fail for whatever reason
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("signup_failure", "We ware unable to create your account");
                }
                redirect('signup'); 
            } else {
                // If email is already in the database
                // urge user to sign in (redirect to signup page too)
                $this->session->set_flashdata("email_exists", "The email address $email already exists in the database. Please signin.");
                redirect('signin'); 
            }
        } else {
            $this->load->view('signup');
        }
}
```

Many thanks to all that helped!

Comment: this is essentially the same as my answer. glad you went with the model approach to verifying email existence though.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing it using the validation function you can easily just call it like so:

`$this->form_validation->is_unique($email, 'users.email')`

As the `is_unique` function expects the first parameter being the string to match and the second being the `table`.`field` according to the source file documentation.

Full code:

```
public function signup()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[cpassword]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');

        $email = $this->input->post('email');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
            $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $date_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $verification_key = md5($email);
            $active = 0;
            $this->load->model('Usermodel');
            // Create account
            if ($this->Usermodel->user_register($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password, $date_created, $date_updated, $verification_key, $active)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("signup_sucess", "Your account was created. Your have to activate it before you can signin. We have send you an activation email at $email.");
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("signup_failure", "We ware unable to create your account");
            }
            redirect('signup');
        } else {
            if (!$this->form_validation->is_unique($email, 'users.email')) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("email_exists", "The email address you provided already exists. Please signin.");
                redirect('signin');
            }
            $this->load->view('signup');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also its generally a good idea to put the matches function on the confirm password, otherwise if the two don't match it will say Password must match Confirm Password where Confirm Password must match Password. It a bit nitpicky, but it makes more logical sense.

Comment: It _almost_ works, but not just yet: the `email_exists` flash message appears on _any_ email related error, not just when the provided email is in the database already.

Comment: You asked if there was a way to use the is_unique function outside the form validation typical usage. This is how you can use it. The logic behind this is sound: `if (!$this->form_validation->is_unique($email, 'users.email')) {` (note exclamation point). As the function ONLY tests if the email is unique it will only trigger the underlying flash message if that is the case. If there are other things happening then you have to explain it better because what you are saying doesn't make much sense.

Comment: note that form validation will fail if the field is not unique automatically triggering the else.

Comment: I got what I was looking for. Look at _my_ answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of  `$this->load->view('signup');` use `redirect('controller/method')` and set your flash message before redirect `$this->session->set_flashdata("signup_failure", "Email alredy exist");`

Replace your below else condition

```
else {
        $this->load->view('signup');
    }
```

With

```
else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata("signup_failure", "Email address <?php echo $this->input->post('email'); ?> alredy exist in our database");
        redirect('signup');
    }
```

Comment: `else {
   $this->load->view('signup');
  }` refers to the case validation failed for _any_ reason, not just existing email.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function signup()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]',
            array('required' => 'Email is Required.'), 
            array('is_unique' => 'Email Already exist.')
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|matches[cpassword]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE)
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
        $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $date_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $date_updated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $verification_key = md5($email);
        $active = 0;
        $this->load->model('Usermodel');
        // Create account
        if ($this->Usermodel->user_register($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password, $date_created, $date_updated ,$verification_key , $active)) 
        {
            // Create a view for Check Email in View.
            $this->load->view('Check_Email_view');
        } 
        else 
        {
            $signup_failure="Something Went Wrong Please Sign Up again.";
            $this->load->view('signup',$signup_failure, true);
            // in view Use Isset($signup_failure)
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $this->load->view('signup');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the role of `// Create a view for Check Email in View.
            $this->load->view('Check_Email_view');`?

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, some explanation would go a long way to improving the quality of your answer.  It also helps others who may come across this answer in the future to understand the solution.

Comment: Check_Email_view is a Success form or success view.